# How to evaluate Modules in a notebook from another notebook?

Tags: functions, front-end, evaluation, notebooks, syntax

I would like to create a notebook populated with several modules and be able to evaluate these modules by running a separate notebook.
I have attempted several uses of the `NotebookEvaluate` command with no luck. Can someone please explain to me how to do this?

More specifically, I would like to have a notebook named "functions.nb" which is populated with several functions, and evaluate this notebook in a notebook named "output.nb" which will call my written functions in "functions.nb", evaluate the functions, and provide the output.

As an example, if functions.nb contains:

```
Add[x0_,y0_]:=
Module[{x=x0,y=y0},
z=x+y
]
```

And output.nb contains:

```
Add[2,5]
```

The output would be:

```
z=7
```

Comment: Have you considered putting the definitions in a plain text file (package) and loading them with `Get`?

Comment: After reading about Packages I still can't figure it out. I made a simple package named "function.m" containing 
'g[x_] := x^2'

In another notebook I ran
'Get["function.m"]'

but I receive a 'Get::noopen: Cannot open function.m. >>' error. What am  I doing wrong?

Comment: You either need to specify the full path to `function.m` or you need to change the working directory to where `function.m` is first.  The working directory is not the same as the notebook directory.  It is given by `Directory[]`.  It can be changed by `SetDirectory[]`.  `SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]` changes the working directory to the notebook directory (if the notebook is saved on disk).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the most straight forward would be to use *Mathematica* packages and importing the definitions in that notebook using the function `Get` as [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) mentioned in the comments. I suggest that you have a closer look at the documentation on [how to set up packages in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SettingUpMathematicaPackages.html). Th principle is quite simple to understand.

Here is a small example of how you can set up a package. You first define your package and its [context](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html) which is called *functions* in this case. Save the file as a *Mathematica* package file (.m). If you want to make a function to be available for other packages and notebooks, you can define a [usage](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DocumentationConstructs.html) for that function in the exported symbols region. This will ensure that this function is available in the global context.

```
(* Mathematica Package *)

BeginPackage["functions`"]
(* Exported symbols added here with SymbolName::usage *)  

myAdd::usage="
myAdd[x0_,y0_]
computes z=x0+y0 and returns the result.
";
Begin["`Private`"] (* Begin Private Context *) 

myAdd[x0_,y0_]:=
Module[{z},
z=x0+y0
]

End[] (* End Private Context *)

EndPackage[]
```

You can then import the content of your package with the function [`Get`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html) and make the functions available in your Mathematica session. This will evaluate the definitions you made in the package functions will be available and you can use them.

```
Get["...pathToPackage...\\functions.m"]
```

By the way I recommend to not define functions that start with capital letters. All built-in functions start with capital letters and you might run into conflicts you don't want. Also you should have another look at local variables and the usage of [Modules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/HowModulesWork.html).

Comment: I got it working! Now I have 5 custom functions in a separate file and my script lengths is reduced by half! Thanks!
I didn't realize I had to specify the path, that's why it was not reading the package.

Comment: How do I do this without having to open and run the `functions.m` file in order to gain access to it? Also how do I make use of unassigned variables, e.g. `bla[]:=x`, without having them appear in the other notebook as ``functions`Private`x``?

Answer (score 7):

In the first notebook:

```
Add[x0_, y0_] := Module[{x = x0, y = y0}, x + y]
Save["myFunction", Add]
```

Or put your first notebook in to C:\Documents

In the second notebook:

```
Get["myFunction"]
Add[1, 2]
```

Comment: How can I replicate your answer above with `CellTags` rather than `myFunction`? I have various initialization cells in `nb1` with `CellTags` and I like to recall these tagged cells from another notebook `nb2`.